# Docs link broken for Docusaurus v2 project

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, blogs, docusaurus

I am building a documentation site using docusaurus (version 2). It gives a 404 on `/docs` PAGE NOT FOUND error.

Links:

1. [My Github Project](https://github.com/AymanArif/docusaurus-blog)
2. [Netlify hosted site](https://ayman-blog.netlify.app/docs)

I am new to docusaurus, and I might have misconfigured my `/docs`. Would appreciate help from the community.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to override the `slug` in the frontmatter on your 'home' docs page to be `/`.

For example, if you wanted your `CleanCode.md` document to become your 'home' page, accessible at `/docs`, then you'd add the following to its frontmatter at the top of the Markdown:

```
slug: /
```

The [Docusaurus v2 docs](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/docs-introduction/#home-page-docs) explain more.